# MYSQL variables in php query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

The solution to this problem might be a simple over sight of mine.

I am trying to run a MYSQL query stored as a string in PHP. The query runs fine using DBM tool like Navicat but returns false in my PHP development enviorment. Is there something I've over looked?

```
SET @running_sum = 0;

SELECT
    TID,
    SumTotal,
    T.`Freight`,
    T.`Insurance`,
    T.`Discount`,
    CONCAT(
        '$',
        FORMAT(
            @running_sum :=@running_sum + SumTotal + T.`Freight` + T.`Insurance` - T.`Discount`,
            2
        )
    ) AS 'Running Total'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TID,
            SUM(Quantity * UnitNetValue) AS SumTotal,
            T.`Freight`,
            T.`Insurance`,
            T.`Discount`
        FROM
            Transactions T
        JOIN `Transactions_Products` P ON T.TransactionID = P.TID
        WHERE
            (
                T.TemplateName = ''
                OR T.TemplateName IS NULL
            )
        AND T. STATUS = 1
        GROUP BY
            TransactionID

    ) AS T;
```

I am executing the query like this;

```
$result = mysql_query($this->query);
```

`$this->query` is a string which holds the above query, as it is displayed to you above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries. Your `SET @running_sum = 0;` is considered a separate query and so you'll have to execute that first:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SET @running_sum = 0;");

$result2 = mysql_query($this->query); // <-- without the SET ... query
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)

---

Side note: The `mysql_*` library is deprecated, it is recommended to upgrade to a modern MySQL library such as [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thank you for your help MrCode. It is much appreciated. I will update my code to take this into account.

Comment: Please also be aware of the security consideration when using mysqli_multi_query() to send multiple queries at once.
With mysqli_multi_query() you open yourself to injected queries like "; DROP DATABASE".
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Answer (score 5):

There is also possible to use `multi_query` method instead of `query` of MySQLi:

```
$query = "SET @running_sum = 0; SELECT ...";
$db_link->multi_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

put variable like this. i guess it should work.

```
 mysql_query("SELECT @i:=0");
 mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET id = @i:=@i+1");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread it. I've deleted my comment. Delete yours too and we can pretend I never said anything. Sorry.